# @@Page.Id@@ in Page Template not pulling tcmid

Tags: 2013, dwt

I've inserted `@@Page.Id@@` into a page template and published pages that use this template, but when viewing the source of the page after publishing, no tcmid is shown.

Any idea why this is not happening?

Comment: Have you ran the page in Template Builder? DO you see the value / is the Page object populated?

Comment: Please enter a code snippet to help diagnose

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try `@@Page.ID@@`

**Code**

```
Master.PageID = "@@Page.ID@@";
Master.PageID = "@@Page.Id@@";
Master.PageID = "@@Page.id@@";
```

**Output**

```
Master.PageID = "tcm:35-32789-64";
Master.PageID = "";
Master.PageID = "";
```

Comment: And the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B843B32A-6D69-42B1-BE0C-FE9AA33EBA6D) for reference.